# In a list of pairs, how can I sort the first number if the second number is the same?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of pairs:

```
nums = [("12",8),("44",9),("33",9)]
```

I have written code to sort the above by the second number; and now I would like to write code to sort them by the first number if the second number is the same, but I am struggling to do this.

How can I write code such that to say if the second number is the same, sort by the first number? I have something like this in mind:

```
for i in range(len(nums)): 
    if nums[i][1] == nums[i:][1]: 
        [map(sorted, lambda x:x[0]???)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nums.sort(key=lambda i: (i[1], i[0]))
```

That's all you need. Produce a tuple of two values, the second number first and the first number second, and that will cause the desired sorting, as Python compares each tuple element by element. Since the first item is a string, you may want to use `int(i[0])` if you need numeric comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer deceze, one more question please- say I wanted to sort the string of number i[0] by each digit rather than the whole number, how can I do this? Would I need to have two sorts?

Comment: This is the issue I have, because if it is just a straight sort, I was aware of the above solution. Sorry, I should have made the question clearer.

Comment: What does that mean, "sort by each digit"? That's what a default string comparison would do…?!

Comment: Ohh I see! I didn't know this. I assumed the default would be comparing the entire numbers rather than one digit at a time. I just tested it, and you are right!

Answer (score 2):

Just use this one liner with `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (x[1], int(x[0])))
[('12', 8), ('33', 9), ('44', 9)]
>>>
```